# Aptana Studio 3 doesn't have a launcher icon

Tags: launcher, aptana-studio

When running Aptana Studio 3, the icon in the Unity launcher is a grey square with a question mark. The icon is present in the Dash.

AptanaStudio3.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Aptana Studio 3
GenericName=Integrated Development Environment
Comment=Aptana Strudio 3 Integrated Development Environment
Exec=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3 %F
TryExec=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
Icon=aptana.xpm
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass="Aptana Studio 3"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/x-javascript;application/x-php;application/x-java;text/x-javascript;text/html;text/plain
Categories=GNOME;Development;IDE;
```

Comment: What is the result of typing into the terminal: `locate aptana.xpm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used `sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new` to create a launcher instead of manually creating one and that worked.

You may need to install [gnome-panel [image: Install gnome-panel]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-panel) first:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

If you want to install the minimum needed for the desktop-item-edit command, use this instead:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install gnome-panel
```