# How to create a custom launcher in Cairo Dock?

Tags: cairo-dock, aptana-studio

I'm trying to create a custom launcher for Aptana Studio in my Cairo Dock. I begun by right click → *Add custom launcher* and I'm stuck at entering the command? What am I supossed to put in there (I tried `./AptanaStudio3` - but it doesn't work). I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

I have already created an `Aptana Studio 3.desktop` file and it has an icon; my only problem is I cannot put it into my cairo dock.

How do I create a custom launcher in Cairo Dock for Aptanan Studio?

Comment: i forgot to mention that i already created an Aptana Studio 3.desktop and it has an icon my only problem is i cannot put it into my cairo dock :(

Answer (score 0):

[Aptana Studio 3 doesn't have a launcher icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333609/aptana-studio-3-doesnt-have-a-launcher-icon)

> sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new

to create a launcher , then drag and drop it into cairo dock

Comment: i forgot to mention that i already created an Aptana Studio 3.desktop and it has an icon my only problem is i cannot put it into my cairo dock :(

Comment: Actually by default the Applications Menu applet is enabled, so you can just drag any program from this menu into the dock.

Comment: That's wierd. cause when im running aptana it automatically be in my dock but when i close it it will also be gone on cairo. What i do on my other application is that I run it so it will be on my dock and then right clicking on it and click the "make it a Launcher" option. that just doesnt work on aptana same goes with update manager.

Answer (score 0):

What I just found that works is dragging the AptanaStudio3.desktop file from wherever you have it stored right onto Cairo Dock. Works like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

I just created a custom launcher and adding the path of aptana `/opt/aptana folder/AptanaStudio3` in the "command on click"